# Chef reciepe 'postgresql' doesn't load libraries

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant

*Already solved by lowering chef version*

I have trouble with [postgresql reciepe](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/postgresql) (v3.0.2). My chef version is 11.4.4.

In `recipes/config_initdb.rb` [there is line](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/postgresql/blob/master/recipes/config_initdb.rb#L22)

```
::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Opscode::PostgresqlHelpers)
```

I see module `Opscode::PostgresqlHelpers` [defined in](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/postgresql/blob/master/libraries/default.rb#L21-L22) `libraries/default.rb`.

But it fails with error `uninitialized constant Chef::Recipe::Opscode`.

Why that library didn't requred and how to fix it?

*EDIT:*

I manually require that module and it began fail with similar error `uninitialized constant Opscode::OpenSSL`.

Looks like no libraries loaded. May be I miss some vagrant/chef setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was resolved by lowering chef version to 10.26.0. I believe there was some incompatibility new chef version with some recipes.

Comment: If that's true, it would be nice if you looked in the [ticketing system](http://tickets.opscode.com) for this issue, and if not found, file one! :)

Comment: No, now I move to Ansible in fact.